# Why perborate is greener bleaching agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, environmental-chemistry, green-chemistry

All I know is, perborate degrades into supposedly less harmful compounds.  But what exactly happens that it is considered greener? Consider say perborate vs. hypochlorite.  Why perborate is "greener"?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hypochlorite):

> Chlorination... can oxidize organic contaminants, producing chloroform and other trihalomethanes, which are carcinogenic, and many hundreds of [other]... by-products.
>
> [W]hen household bleach and wastewater were mixed, 1–2% of the available chlorine was observed to form [halogenated] organic compounds."

Perborates, [percarbonates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_percarbonate) and similar bleaching agents, while strong oxidizers, will not create these chlorocarbon chemicals (unless the chlorine is also supplied).

However, boron and perborates are not entirely "green". Boron compounds are [somewhat toxic](http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp26-c2.pdf). If the prices were the same, I'd prefer percarbonate bleach to perborate.